# Use a button to set values in drop down using dash

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash

I was wondering is it possible to set multiple values to a drop down value using a button. What I want to be able to do is filter the drop down and then if the user presses the submit button, all options that contain the search_value are added as the drop down value. For example in my code, if you type in 'a' into the drop down search bar then 'Montreal' and 'San Francisco' appear. If the user were to then press the submit button both these options should be added as values to the drop down at once. At the moment I am able to save the most recent search value to user put in but I am having trouble dynamically altering the drop down value. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Here is my code: FYI: I am running this in a Colab Notebook

**Correct answer

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash  # pip install dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input, State
import pandas as pd  # pip install pandas
import plotly.express as px
import dash_table
import math

from dash import no_update

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = JupyterDash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

options = [
    {"label": "New York City", "value": "NYC"},
    {"label": "Montreal", "value": "MTL"},
    {"label": "San Francisco", "value": "SF"},
]
app.layout = html.Div([
        html.Div(id='output_data'),
        html.Div(id="hidden-search-value", style={"visibility":"hidden"}),
        html.Div(id="value-test", style={'color':'white'}),
        html.Div(html.Button('Submit', id = 'button', n_clicks=0), style={'width':'49%', 'display':'inline-block'}),


    html.Div(
        dcc.Dropdown(id="my-multi-dynamic-dropdown", multi=True, clearable = True, options = options, style={'width':'49%', 'display':'inline-block'})),
])


@app.callback(
    [Output("hidden-search-value", "children"),
    Output("value-test", "children")],
    Input(component_id="my-multi-dynamic-dropdown", component_property="search_value"),
)
# save previous search value in hidden variable 
def update_hidden_value(value):
    if value == "":
        raise PreventUpdate
    return value, "Select all values containing '{}'".format(value)

@app.callback(
        Output("my-multi-dynamic-dropdown", "value"),
        Input(component_id="button", component_property="n_clicks"),
    [
        State(component_id="output_data", component_property="children"),
        State(component_id="hidden-search-value", component_property="children")
    ]
)
# submit button logic: use saved search value to update drop_down value 
def update_multi_options(n_clicks, children, search_value):
    # submit button pressed
    if int(n_clicks) > 0:
      values = []
      for o in options:
        # all values containing search value
        if search_value.lower() in o["label"].lower():
          values.append(o["value"])
        else:
          continue
      return values
    else:
      return no_update

app.run_server(mode='inline', port=8030)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have the wrong ordering of your input arguments to your callback `update_multi_options`. It should be:

```
@app.callback(
    Output("my-multi-dynamic-dropdown", "value"),
    Input(component_id="button", component_property="n_clicks"), 
    State(component_id="output_data", component_property="children")
)
def update_multi_options(n_clicks, children):
```

Now, regarding the dynamic updating using the search feature, it turns out that whenever you click out of the search bar, the `search_value` is cleared. So I suggest perhaps tracking the search_value in a temporary hidden variable, *if* this is a low risk option for your application. An approach to do this would be the following:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
        html.Div(id='output_data'),
        html.Div(html.Button('Submit', id = 'button', n_clicks=0)),
        html.Div(id="hidden-search-value", style={"visibility":"hidden"}),

    html.Div([
        "Multi dynamic Dropdown",
        dcc.Dropdown(id="my-multi-dynamic-dropdown", multi=True, clearable = True, options = options),
    ]),
])
.
.
.
@app.callback(
    Output("my-multi-dynamic-dropdown", "value"),
    [
        Input(component_id="button", component_property="n_clicks"),
    ],
    [
        State(component_id="output_data", component_property="children"),
        State(component_id="hidden-search-value", component_property="children")
    ]
)
def update_multi_options(n_clicks, children, search_value):
    # Make sure that the set values are in the option list, else they will disappear
    # from the shown select list, but still part of the `value`.
    if int(n_clicks) > 0:
      values = []
      for o in options:
        if search_value in o["label"]:
          values.append(o)
        else:
          continue
      return values
    else:
      return no_update

@app.callback(
    Output("hidden-search-value", "children"),
    Input(component_id="my-multi-dynamic-dropdown", component_property="search_value"),
)
def update_hidden_value(value):
    print(value, type(value))
    if value == "":
        raise PreventUpdate
    return value
```

The only limitation with this approach would be that when you type something into the search and click submit, then you manually erase the search value and re-click on submit, it'll be stuck on the last typed in value. But, I don't see this being an issue, since you can overwrite this with another callback if this is undesirable.

In summary, you'll need to track the value you are typing in (eg. `dcc.Dropdown.search_value`) then trigger the filtering.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! With your input I am so close to a working solution. My only issue now is that the output is not displaying in the drop down select bar even though output is set to 'Output("my-multi-dynamic-dropdown", "value")'. I was testing and I know the value of the variable 'values' is correct it's just that it doesn't update the drop downs 'value'. Is it possible to have the values variable displaying in the drop downs select bar when submit is pressed?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are after exactly. With the code I shared in my answer, when submit is pressed, the value/s is/are displayed in the bar (as a light blue highlighted choice/s). Is this what you are seeking to do or do you want the selected values to be displayed in the dropdown choices as well?

Comment: I was looking for the values to to be displayed in the bar (as light blue highlighted choices). For some reason your code did not do this for me but by slightly altering it and setting it to values.append(o['value']) it now works as intended! Thanks again!

Comment: Great to hear, can you please edit my answer with your code and then flagging it as the answer so other users know this solves your issue? Cheers